# How to upload foders using Github desktop

Tags: github, github-desktop

I'm very new to Github and I'm trying to create a new repository that contains 2 folders ("`server`" and "`utalk`").

The "`utalk`" folder is my front-end and the "`server`" folder is my backend.

But when I use Github Desktop, it seems I only push the `server` folder and cant push the `utalk` folder.
I don't know how to push all my folders.

my Project Folder:
[image: my Project Folder]

my GitHub repository:
[image: my GitHub repository]

Comment: I don't understand much. Can you explain more

Comment: Folders only exist in git if they have at least 1 file in them. I haven't used github desktop specifically, but it is probably something like this causing your issue.

Comment: oh, my folders contain many files

Comment: Are you committing them all? Consider adding some more detail to your question such as the error(s) that happen when you try to commit + push them :)

Comment: It has no error. It just only has server folder in the repository and doesn't have  front folder

Comment: I added 2 pictures, you can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in your file explorer, enable [View hidden files](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/)

[image]

Then check if you see a `.git` in the `utalk` folder. That would make it a nested git repository, mostly ignored by your parent folder.

Switch to command-line and do a `git status` in `utalk-project` to know more about your current situation.